# Itemized / Enumarte List structure in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I was wondering, if there is any way to have an enumeration using `LaTeX` to have something like:

```
1. (a) Some text, some text

   (b) Some more text

2. (a) Yet some more text

   (b) Something more ...
```

Please note that I can very well have

```
1. Somethig  here ...

   (a) Some text

   (b) Some more text

2. Another text

   (a) Something here ...

   (b) Etc. etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you show is simply the default behaviour of `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]